# How to remove the yellow border from dropdowns on google chrome?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can i remove the yellow border from dropdowns on google chrome?

The textboxes are ok, they show that great blue outline, but the dropdowns don't.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove the outline by making it transparent like so:

```
select:focus {
   outline-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: @LeandroFaria Try setting the `!important` flag on that property, like so: `select, select:focus { outline:none !important }`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this instead:

```
.bootstrap-select .btn:focus {
   outline-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Because it converts the select to a button, with a list element. The button then gets a class set to it - the above one.

// mcardle

Comment: Maybe the !important is not necessary ;)